# JMP0811I-U Fujitsu runtime error after compiling Fujitsu COBOL with DB2 SQL: cause/remedy?

Tags: db2, cobol, netcobol

I'm able to (on Windows XP) precompile, compile and link a sample (Fujitsu NetCobol) COBOL test program which contains embedded SQL. This test program is to read and display the number of rows in a DB2 (UDB 9.5 on Linux) database table.

At runtime I get following error message:

**JMP0811I-U [PID:... TID:...] FAILURE IN LINKAGE RULES OR PARAMETER OF THE 'sqlgstrt' PROGRAM. PGM=DB2TST1**

The precompile source code this error refers to looks as follows:

```
     * ... in WORKING-STORAGE section:

      01  SQLA-PROGRAM-ID.
       05 SQL-PART1 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 172.
       05 SQL-PART2 pic X(6) value "AEAMAI".
       05 SQL-PART3 pic X(24) value "gBSdTdJY01111 2         ".
       05 SQL-PART4 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 13.
       05 SQL-PART5 pic X(13) value "ADMINISTRATOR".
       05 SQL-PART6 pic X(115) value LOW-VALUES.
       05 SQL-PART7 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 8.
       05 SQL-PART8 pic X(8) value "COBOL/DB".
       05 SQL-PART9 pic X(120) value LOW-VALUES.

      * .. in PROCEDURE DIVISION:

      *EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :DB-SERVER USER :DB-USER USING :DB-PWD
      *     END-EXEC
           CALL "sqlgstrt" USING
              BY CONTENT SQLA-PROGRAM-ID
              BY VALUE 0
              BY REFERENCE SQLCA
```

Does anybody know what this error message means?

Comment: if I had 1 more karma point, I'd do it for you, but you should change the "cobol." tag to remove the trailing "."

Answer (score 1):

The error description was due to:
 *) the CHECK(LINKAGE) compiler option
    (only available in NetCOBOL for Windows, not for Linux)
    without this option, the error is still there, but even less descriptive

The actual error was due to:
 *) the `CALL "sqlgstrt" USING ...` generated by the DB2 precompiler implies the wrong
    (= COBOL) calling convention => manually changing the calls to 
    `CALL "sqlgstrt" WITH STDCALL LINKAGE USING...` has resolved the runtime error

This solution implies changing the precompiler results though, so I'm still in search of a DB2 precompiler option to generate the right CALLs.